# Vector Subscript Out of Range C++ SFML

Tags: c++, vector, sfml

I'm trying to make a program that randomly generates a user-defined number of circles on the screen (using SFML), but when I choose a number of circles above 6, I get the Vector Subscript Out of Range error. Any number = to or below 6 works as expected.

I've tried looking up the error message, but none of the answers i've seen apply to my code. The code breaks at the first for loop, but if I comment out the first loop, it breaks at the second loop.

Here is my code:

```
#include "SFML/Graphics.hpp"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    const int WINDOW_X = 800;
    const int WINDOW_Y = 480;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(WINDOW_X, WINDOW_Y), "Epidemic Simulation", sf::Style::Close | sf::Style::Titlebar);

    int numPeople = 10;
    float size = 5;
    int status = 0;

    std::vector<sf::CircleShape> person(size);

    for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; ++i)
    {
        if (status == 0)
            person[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
        else if (status == 1)
            person[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);
        else if (status == 2)
            person[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
        else
        {
            std::cout << ("Error: Incorrect color value");
            person[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
        }
        person[i].setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; ++i)
    {
        int xPos = rand() % WINDOW_X - (size * 2);
        int yPos = rand() % WINDOW_Y - (size * 2);

        if (xPos < (size * 2))
            xPos = 0;

        if (yPos < (size * 2))
            yPos = 0;

        std::cout << ("X position: ") << xPos << (", Y position: ") << yPos << "\n";

        person[i].setPosition(xPos, yPos);
        person[i].setRadius(size);
    }

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);

        for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; ++i)
            window.draw(person[i]);

        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is `size` a `float`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you initiate person(size) with `size = 5` and the loop is going up to `numPeople = 10`. You probably wanted to write:

```
std::vector<sf::CircleShape> person(numPeople);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks! I thought that the variable inside the parenthesis was supposed to change the radius of the circle, not the number of circles. When I change from size to numPeople it changes the number, so how would I go about changing the radius of the circles?

Comment: It is already there, the size variable controls the radius: `person[i].setRadius(size);`